# Saving DOCX Documents to a server

Tags: c#, macos, server

I put you in situation in C# I'm realizing a program that modifies DOCX documents and creates new documents both DOCX and PDF. In local I do it perfectly but when I want DOCX to read it from the server or save it on the server does not do it to me, the maximum is that it opens the folder in which it is stored on the server but with the document does nothing . Comment that the program I am developing for MAC OSX and the server is Windows Server.
Someone can tell me the code I can use.

To read usage:

**Process.Start ("smb // servername / folder / doc.docx");**

Also tried by giving you username and password:

**Process.Start (serverpaths, user, password, "");**

To save to the server and create document:
PDF use the iTextSharp library:

**PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance (doc, new FileStream (path, FileMode.Create);**

Comment: "smb // servername / folder / doc.docx" - shouldn't it be "smb://servername/folder/doc.docx" ?

Comment: `smb // servername // folder // doc.docx` try with this. i dont know if it help am happy

Comment: Hello: First thank you for your help.
@Fildor If I use the two points after smb that copied it I have gone to put them. Thank you again.

Comment: Hello: First thank you for your help.

 @JojiThomasEapen  the double // is also tested.
Thank you again.

Comment: then can u provide ur code, which u tried

Comment: Is smb an actual folder or smb like in Samba?

Comment: @Fildor like in samba